# Changing variable names

Tags: string-manipulation

In Mathematica, I am doing computations involving polynomials with variables like

```
p[0,1,2]
```

In the end, I will need to put these equations in to another program. This other program does not allow brackets or commas in variable names. So, I need to send the above variable to

```
p012
```

Ultimately, I need my entire list of polynomials to be in input form which I can copy and paste into the other program. I have tried writing something like

```````
StringVar[i_, j_, k_] := StringForm["p``````", i, j, k]
```````

And then using Simplify to substitute the variables. But, when I use InputForm on the entire list of polynomials I get these funny expressions

```````
StringForm["p``````", 0, 1, 2]
```````

instead of the variables p012 that I would like. How do I make Mathematica treat these as variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is to give `p` a [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format):

```
Format[p[a__Integer], InputForm] := SequenceForm[p,a]
```

Here is an example polynomial, and what it looks like when converted to [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm):

```
poly = 2 p[0,1,2]^2 + p[1,2,3]^3
% //InputForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a common trap with using `StringForm[]`. But before discussing the pitfall, let me offer slightly simpler code:

```
With[{expr = p[0, 1, 2]},
     StringForm["`1``2`", Head[expr], StringJoin[ToString /@ (List @@ expr)]]]
   p012
```

Looks good so far, but let's see what `InputForm[]` says:

```
InputForm[%]
   StringForm["`1``2`", p, "012"]
```

Certainly not a string!

So, you need an additional `ToString[]`:

```
ToString[%] // InputForm
   "p012"
```

---

The alternative in newer versions of *Mathematica* is `StringTemplate[]`, which produces a genuine string. Observe:

```
With[{expr = p[0, 1, 2]},
     StringTemplate["`head``args`"] @
     <|"head" -> Head[expr], "args" -> StringJoin[ToString /@ (List @@ expr)]|>]
   "p012"
```

Comment: ...and you can then use `Symbol["p012"]` much later if you really want symbols instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, this is the replacement rule you're looking for:

```
rule = p[i_, j_, k_] :> ToExpression[StringJoin @@ (ToString /@ {"p", i, j, k})]
```

You might also consider using `Format` and/or `$PrePrint` to have the expressions automatically formatted.